# Webscraper, 'NoneType' object to string TypeError. What is creating the nonetype, and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, typeerror, nonetype

I have some code that's returning the following error:

TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicity

I've looked at other instances of people getting the same type of error and asking questions about it on here:

From what I can tell, the cause of the error can vary wildly depending on the cause of the NoneType within the code. Many of the cases I've seen haven't helped me because it was clear (or made clear by users here) what was causing the NoneType, and possible solutions. I'm very new to Python, and I can't work out what is creating the error in my code.

I'm trying to create a basic webscraper for a site that hosts texts. What I want it to do is create a list of URLs which link to these texts, as well as a title for each one. Here is my original code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Running this returns only links at the top of the page and from the tab bar.
# No links to Irish language texts are returned.
# Causes TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

def celt_crawl(max_pages):
    url = 'http://celt.ucc.ie/irlpage.html'
    source_code =  requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        # Next line causes error by creating 'NoneType'
        href = "http://celt.ucc.ie/" + link.get('href')
        name = link.string
        print(href)
        print(name)
        # The name of the tab bar link is returned where present.
        # This should ideally print the name of the relevant text.

celt_crawl (1)
```

I've marked the problem like with a note.

I've tried to fix the issue in a couple of ways. First I assumed that the `link.get('href')` might be causing issues by returning null values, then I assumed it might be the `name = link.string`. I tried the following two if statements to fix it but both return the same TypeError.

Fix 1.

```
if link.get('href') is None:
    pass
else:
    print(href)
    print(name)
```

Fix 2.

```
href = "http://celt.ucc.ie/" + link.get('href')
name = link.string
if name is None:
    pass
else:
    print(href)
    print(name)
```

I assumed that either the name or the href was returning a null value and causing the code to break when this was encountered resulting in both the TypeError, and and issue whereby only the URLs for the tab bar are returned, and none of the links to the texts which is all I actually want.

If anyone can provide an explanation/solution I'd be really grateful.

Edit to include Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admd9\Desktop\Coding\Python\Web Crawlers\Web Crawler CELT.py", line 22, in <module>
    celt_crawl (1)
  File "C:\Users\admd9\Desktop\Coding\Python\Web Crawlers\Web Crawler CELT.py", line 15, in celt_crawl
    href = "http://celt.ucc.ie/" + link.get('href')
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Comment: Hey @roganjosh Sorry for leaving that out. I've edited my post to include the traceback. Hope that's everything.

Comment: So you have an `a` element that doesn't have an `href` attribute... `link.get('href')` will return `None` in that case - hence your error... So what shoulud happen in those cases?

Comment: You may be able to get away with `for link in soup.find_all(a, href=True)` which'll only retrieve elements which do have an href attribute...

Comment: That must be a link to the top/bottom of the page, or some other link within the page. I hadn't even considered that possibility (I'm no good with HTML). Ideally I'd omit such results.

@JonClements Thanks for the advice. Using `('a', href=True)` worked perfectly.

Comment: You asked for an explanation. It is that python 3 does not allow implicit concatenation of different types, for instance strings and integers, string and Nonetype and so on. You have to do this explicitly by declaring it. So when you try to join a string like &quot;www.whatever.com&quot; + None, that causes an error. Solution is to test if the joining parts are None first, and if so pass. The pythonian way would be placing the concat in a try except block and pass if that raises an exception.